# Linux Bluetooth programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bluetooth, bluez

I am making a desktop application to connect with an embedded device. I was going to use Windows but due to lack of proper examples and documentation I decided to go with Linux bluez development. Can someone suggest a good resource to go about programming for bluez. I found a MIT documentation but that was about it.

Answer (score 2):

bluez uses [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) for communication. Use [D-Feet](https://fedorahosted.org/d-feet/) to inspect the `org.bluez` interface so that you can write against the D-Bus API appropriately.

Comment: thanx, can you tell me where is the official documentation for bluez stack?

Answer (score 1):

I've also been looking for info on Bluetooth application development in the Linux environment and came across this pretty good resource http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite good book [Bluetooth Essentials for Programmers](http://www.btessentials.com/). It has section for both  Windows and Linux bluetooth stack. At least you can look at sources of chapter examples on the book site.

Comment: Link seems dead, but here's the book http://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-Essentials-Programmers-Albert-Huang/dp/0521703751/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1321220954&sr=8-1.